# process "events" async with elixir and phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework, gen-server, elixir

I'm using phoenix controllers to receive data via REST calls. So an iOS app could send the "events" for each user and based on the event, I need to calculate the score/points and send it back to the user. Calculation and sending back to the user can happen asynchronously. I'm using Firebase to communicate back to the user.

What is a good pattern to do calculation? Calculate could be bunch of database queries to determine the score of that event. Where should this calculation happen? Background workers, GenEvent, streams within user-specific GenServer (I have supervised GenServer per user).

Comment: I'm still a little unclear about what you're trying to accomplish in the end. Also are you using [channels](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/channels)?

Comment: Please see updated description

Comment: So to be clear you're not actually sending back the info via a response to the REST call?

Comment: I can't speek authoritatively but I think what you want is a Task: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/task-and-gen-tcp.html#tasks

Comment: Correct. REST APIs does not get give any response back other then 200 OK. What about GenEvent?

Comment: GenEvent would work as well, however I think task is specifically made for one-off kinds of things which makes it a more appropriate abstraction. I may be wrong on that one though.

Comment: I agree - either a Task or a GenServer sounds like the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: If I use GenServer, wouldn't it block and process them serially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at [Phoenix channels](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/channels), [tasks](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Task.html) and [GenServer](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html).

Additionally, if you would like to manage a pool of GenServer workers to do the calculations and maybe send back the results for you, check out [Conqueuer](https://hex.pm/packages/conqueuer).  I wrote this library and it is in use in production systems for my company.  It is uses [poolboy](https://hex.pm/packages/poolboy), which is probably the most pervasive pool management library in Erlang/Elixir.

Admittedly, I do not fully understand the requirements of your system, but it does not seem to me `GenEvent` has a place in your requirements.  `GenEvent` is about distributing events to one or more consumers of events.  So unless you have a graph of processes that need to subscribe to events being emitted from other parts of your system I do not see a role for it.

Comment: I ended up using  Conqueuer library.

Comment: Is it possible to get the instance of the worker? I'm using RethinkDB elixir client driver which requires connection to be initialized as 
`defmodule FooDatabase do
  use RethinkDB.Connection
end`

So I defined my worker in conqueuer as FooDatabase.

Comment: Conqueuer does not expose a way to gain access to a worker, as there is a pool of workers.  You should just pass the work to the pool and it will handle it for you, depending on your naming something like: `Conqueuer.work(:foo_databases, some_args_here)`.  If you are trying to gain access to a specific worker from your pool of workers, I would question your design.  Do you actually need a pool?  Do you actually need to access a worker directly?